# Need to export a Symantec Code signing certificate as .pfx

Tags: powershell, windows-phone, certificate, code-signing, symantec

I need to export a Symantec Code signing certificate for signing .xap as .pfx. The steps mentioned on official website state All Tasks>Export as .pfx but the option is grayed out. For pvk2pfx.exe we need a .pvk which is not provided. I have only a .cer file wwhich ii want to concert into a .pfx file with a password. Kindly suggest me the steps and suitable tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .cer file was without the key. A small key icon appears next  to the certificate name in microsoft certificate snap-in. Regenerating  the certificates did the task!